# How to add additional Apple apps to the Xcode 10 simulator?

Tags: xcode, native, simulator

I looked but couldn't find an answer to this. I would like for additional Apple apps to appear in the simulator like Weather, Mail, Notes, etc. They're missing when I launch the simulator and I need them to test my app. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If the option is there its more helpful for all developer, but unfortunately there is no option to install the apps. you (We) should check in real device only. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, it seems that it is not possible to do this. You have to use a physical device to interact with the native apps unavailable in the simulator.